# Reaction to increase and diminish mass at will (forward and reverse reactions)

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, thermoelectricity

Non-professional question... Is there currently a method for converting mass to/from another form of energy? This would be like an exothermic reaction in that mass is consumed, but it would also have to be controllable and reversible.

Practically, this would mean being able to control the mass of a given object (to some extent.)

Any ideas or reactions that we know of? Is this even physically possible within a controlled environment?

Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear reactions convert a tiny amount of mass into energy when splitting an atom into parts. This works with big atoms like uranium. If you control it, you have a nuclear reactor. If not, you have a bomb. Very exothermic indeed.

It is controlled by slowing down the number of atoms per second that split. It isn't reversible. You would have to put all that energy back into the atoms.

Fusion reactions are similar, but you convert a small amount of mass into energy when you fuse two atoms into one bigger atom. This works with small atoms like hydrogen. People have tried to make controllable reactors, but they fizzle out. Bombs are of course possible.

The Sun is a giant fusion reactor that is very stable and has run for a very long time. The center of the Sun is at a temperature of millions of degrees and under extreme pressure. We can't reproduce those conditions on earth, except in very short bursts.

You get a huge amount of energy from converting a tiny amount of mass. So this isn't a way to make an object less massive.

Answer (score 0):

According to Relativity, if the energy of a body **in its rest frame** is changed, also its mass will change according to
$$
\Delta E = \Delta m c^2.
$$
You see that it is perfectly possible to vary the mass of a body reversibly by just adding or subtracting energy by whatever means (it is not necessary to use nuclear reactions). At the same time, the coefficient $c^2$ shows how unpractical it would be under normal laboratory conditions. To increase the body's mass by $10^{-6}$ kg, one should provide about $10^{11}$ J.